# itk::OpenCVImageBridge has not been declared

Tags: opencv, itk

I believe I built **ITK** with the **opencv bridge**.  But when I compile my code, I'm getting an error that says:

> error: 'itk::OpenCVImageBridge' has not been declared

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's how ITK was built:

```
cmake -D BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -D BUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -D Module_ITKVideoBridgeOpenCV:BOOL=ON -D Module_ITKReview:BOOL=ON -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably forgetting to `#include <itkOpenCVImageBridge.h>`

Comment: I think this is what happened: There was a header file that compiled just fine in the past, even though it was missing the include directive.  But the programs that were calling it, had the include directive.  It should have been in this header file in the first place.  Wow.  Thank you so much.